# Concat multiple dataframes in python with names as index

Tags: python, dataframe

Is there any way to concat multiple dataframes into one, but getting the name of each dataframe as index, or in the best case, get as a new column?

I have 17 dataframes and i want a identifier to know which data belongs to which dataframe.

i have these list of dataframes

frames = [fp_2015, fp_2016, fp_2017, fp_2018,  fp_2019,  fp_2020, res_FirmPrivs_2016,
res_FirmPrivs_2017,  res_FirmPrivs_2018, res_FirmPrivs_2019, res_FirmPrivs_2020,
res_uai_2015, res_uai_2016,res_uai_2017,res_uai_2018, res_uai_2019,  res_uai_2020]

I'd like to get something like this:

| Dataframe_name | Institucion | filename | link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fp_2015. | CONACAFE. | RIA-CGR-001-15-AFYC-CONACAFE | index.php/repositorio/send/23-cgr/1977-ria-cg |
| fp_2016 | CiudadSandino | RIA-CGR-001-15-AFYC-CONACAFE | /index.php/repositorio/send/23-cgr/1977-ria-cg.. |

I get these DF by extracting it from a website, i have it individually but documentation of pandas does not give a solution with concatenate function, just to assign it manually with "keys".

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can use `MultiIndex` feature of pandas data frames. Read here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html

Comment: Do all the dataframes you are looking to combine have the same columns and data types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using simple example data, here's what you're trying to do:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, concat

dfs = {
    'kids1': DataFrame([
        {'id': 'A', 'name': 'Alice', 'age': 12},
        {'id': 'B', 'name': 'Bob', 'age': 13}
    ]).set_index('id'),
    'kids2': DataFrame([
        {'id': 'B', 'name': 'Beau', 'age': 9},
        {'id': 'C', 'name': 'Carla', 'age': 11}
    ]).set_index('id')
}

# just two regular dataframes
print(dfs['kids1'])
print(dfs['kids2'])

result = concat([
    df.assign(source=name).reset_index().set_index(['source', 'id']) 
    for name, df in dfs.items()
], axis=0)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
     name  age
id            
A   Alice   12
B     Bob   13

     name  age
id            
B    Beau    9
C   Carla   11

            name  age
source id            
kids1  A   Alice   12
       B     Bob   13
kids2  B    Beau    9
       C   Carla   11
```

And this now allows things like:

```
print(result.loc['kids1'])

print(result.loc[result.index.get_level_values(1)=='B'])  # or:
print(result.loc[(slice(None), slice('B', 'B')), :])
```

Output:

```
     name  age
id            
A   Alice   12
B     Bob   13

           name  age
source id           
kids1  B    Bob   13
kids2  B   Beau    9

           name  age
source id           
kids1  B    Bob   13
kids2  B   Beau    9
```

The `result` is created from a dictionary of dataframes, to avoid dealing with variable names (which you shouldn't involve in your data), instead of a list of variables.

It's created using `pd.concat()`, over `axis=0`, i.e. combining the rows of the dataframes involved.

This part:

```
df.assign(source=name).reset_index().set_index(['source', 'id'])
```

Takes each of the dataframes, adds a column called `'source'` and sets it to the name (key) from the dictionary. It then resets the index (to get access to the `id` columns) and sets the index to be a combination of the `'source'` and `'id'` columns.

Comment: All the dataframes has same columns. If i understood well, do i need to have a dict of the dataframes first? Is it a way to concat all the dataframes adding the name of the dataframe as index or new column?

Comment: I only created a dict of dataframes because that gives you access to their names. After all, it doesn't make sense to refer to `'fp_2015'` in the resulting data, just because the *variable* was called `fp_2015` (it's a common mistake among beginning programmers to involve the names of variables in their data, but there's no point and it causes all sorts of horrors maintaining your code). However, you could also just loop over the dataframes in a list and label them `1`, `2`, etc. - or whatever.

Comment: Another way of looking at it: where's that name coming from? Are you naming the dataframe `fp_2015` because of something in the original data? Or in a filename? If so, you should probably retain that information in data (like the key of a dictionary) and not in the name of the variable.

Comment: Ok. So, i want to keep the dataframe names because then i need to create a couple of columns from that name. For example, one column for "unit" and get from "fp" for "fondos_propios and "res_FirmPrivs" for "firmasPrivs". The secondo column would be for the year, so i would get the year for each row depending on the name. The thing is that when i concat all the dataframe it gets me 5818 registers.

Comment: Ok, i just find a way to do what i wanted. i concatenated all the dataframes with a list of them and create a tuple with also their names to put it as keys. Then i reset the index and get what i wanted. Thank you for your help, it help me a lot to understand the logic.

Comment: Yes, that's a very good way to solve it. With the names in a list or tuple, you've pulled the names into the data of the program instead of the code - much better, and easier to change and update later.